# A way to "cache" a value in Puppeteer's waitForFunction?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Is there a way to "cache" a value in Puppeteer's browser-based functions?

The callback passed to `page.waitForFunction( .. )` is running on every `DOMMutation` from the puppeteer option `polling: "mutation"`. So it could potentially run `500` times and execute `const listEl = document.querySelector("#list")` `500 times`.

I was wondering if there is a way to cache `listEl` when it's found so that next time the callback is invoked `querySelector("#listEl")` does not have to run again and the cached value inside `listEl` is used.

```js
await page.waitForFunction(
    () => {
      const listEl = document.querySelector("#list");
    },
    {
      polling: "mutation",
    }
  );
})();
```

The callback inside `waitForFunction( ..)` has no access to variables outside the function. Because the callback runs (injected) inside Browser context and the outside environment is node.js.

Comment: Your callback never returns anything.

Comment: @IngoBürk I haven't added the logic yet, I'm afraid it's gonna impact performance (which is important here) as I have to do a lot of operations during every mutation.

Comment: You can always access `window` and store it there, that's the same as a global variable (you have access to `document`, so I figure that should work).

Comment: @IngoBürk gonna try that should work indeed! I will use that for now. I just discovered "memoization" after some googling, would that be of any use?

Comment: You could attach this to the window with `listEl = listEl || document.querySelector("#list")`, but this code doesn't make sense because `waitForFunction` never returns anything other than undefined, so it'll time out. Do you mean to `return listEl` at the end? In that case, you might want to use `waitForSelector`, then access the element from Node. All of this strikes me as a potential micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it a window property:

```
window.listEl = window.listEl || document.querySelector("#list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
As `puppeteer` is using `chromium`, `localStorage` is therefore supported.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
});
```

You could even probably pass the `localStorage` value through different executions on a same domain via [`userDataDir` launch option](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions).

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: './temp/',
  // ...
});
```

Comment: You can only save strings though. It can't work for DOM elements.

Comment: @pguardiario Sure, tho you can save a DOM el as a string and convert it back again to a DOM el afterwards.

Comment: No you really can't. At least not in a way that will still be attached to DOM.